# How to draw a bounding box on an element with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, webautomation

I am super new to Puppeteer and JS, but I was wondering how can find an element on a webpage and draw a bounding box around it so if I do a screenshot the box will be visible (I want the screenshot of the whole page but want to see also the bounding box.

Comment: Please, share your code with us.

Answer (score 5):

This code will add a red border in your question and take a screenshot of it.

```js
await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225525/how-to-draw-a-bounding-box-on-an-element-with-puppeteer");
const element = await page.$(".question");
await page.evaluate(el => el.style.border = "5px solid red", element);
await element.screenshot({ path: "./question.png"});
```